# The below code for finding Cheapest Fare is giving "Time Limit Exceeded" for one test case

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, dijkstra

Details:

- There are `n` cities connected by `m` flights. Each fight starts from city `u` and arrives at `v` with a price `w`.
- Now given all the cities and fights, together with starting city `src` and the destination `dst`, your task is to find the cheapest price from `src` to `dst` with up to `k stops`. If there is no such route, output `-1.`

Example1:

```
Input: 
n = 3, edges = [[0,1,100],[1,2,100],[0,2,500]]
src = 0, dst = 2, k = 1
Output: 200
```

Example2:

```
Input: 
n = 3, edges = [[0,1,100],[1,2,100],[0,2,500]]
src = 0, dst = 2, k = 0
Output: 500
```

My Code:

```
n = 4
flights = [[0,1,100],[1,2,100],[2,0,100],[1,3,600],[2,3,200]]
src = 0
dst = 3
k = 1

def solution(n, flights, src, dst, k):
    from collections import defaultdict
    import heapq as hq
    
    graph = defaultdict(dict)
    for s, d, w in flights:
        graph[s][d] = w
    
    heap = [(0, src, k+1)]
    hq.heapify(heap)
    
    while heap:
        minCost, dest, redges = hq.heappop(heap)  #redges => remaining edges
        if redges>=0:
            if dest == dst: return minCost
            
        for neighbor, weight in graph[dest].items():
            if redges>=0:
                hq.heappush(heap, (minCost+weight, neighbor, redges-1))
        
    return -1
```

I am getting `700` which is correct result but it is failing with `Time Limit Exceeded` with below input.

Is there a way to introduce `break` in above code?

```
13
[[11,12,74],[1,8,91],[4,6,13],[7,6,39],[5,12,8],[0,12,54],[8,4,32],[0,11,4],[4,0,91],[11,7,64],[6,3,88],[8,5,80],[11,10,91],[10,0,60],[8,7,92],[12,6,78],[6,2,8],[4,3,54],[3,11,76],[3,12,23],[11,6,79],[6,12,36],[2,11,100],[2,5,49],[7,0,17],[5,8,95],[3,9,98],[8,10,61],[2,12,38],[5,7,58],[9,4,37],[8,6,79],[9,0,1],[2,3,12],[7,10,7],[12,10,52],[7,2,68],[12,2,100],[6,9,53],[7,4,90],[0,5,43],[11,2,52],[11,8,50],[12,4,38],[7,9,94],[2,7,38],[3,7,88],[9,12,20],[12,0,26],[10,5,38],[12,8,50],[0,2,77],[11,0,13],[9,10,76],[2,6,67],[5,6,34],[9,7,62],[5,3,67]]
10
1
10
```

[Source](https://efficientcodeblog.wordpress.com/2018/02/22/cheapest-flight-with-given-number-of-stops-application-of-dijkstras-algorithm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your algorithm allows cycles. That increases the amount of possibilities immensly.

The original code needs almost 16 millions iteration to find the solution. The modification below cuts that down to about 30 thousands

We need to record the route, I added an item here:

```
heap = [(0, src, [src], k+1)]
#                ^^^^^
```

It could be a set (more efficient), but an ordered list gives you some information about the solution, like that in this case it is `[10, 5, 8, 7, 4, 0, 12, 2, 11, 6, 3, 9]`

Then avoid returning to any stop already visited on the route.

```
heap = [(0, src, [src], k+1)]
hq.heapify(heap)
   
while heap:
    minCost, dest, route, redges = hq.heappop(heap)  #redges => remaining edges
    if redges>=0:
        if dest == dst: return minCost

    for neighbor, weight in graph[dest].items():
        if redges>=0 and neighbor not in route:
            hq.heappush(heap, (minCost+weight, neighbor, route + [neighbor], redges-1))
```

Note: `if redges>=0` could be probably `>0`

Comment: thanks a lot.  can you please provide some example to help understand how my algorithm is allowing cycles?

Comment: For example the `flights` data contain edges 0->11 (weight 4) and 11->0 (weight 13). Your code considers all neighbours. At node 11 it will push to heap a tuple with 0 as the new temporary destination and at node 0 it will push a tuple with 11. As long as the edges limit alows, it can and it will go 0->11->0->11 etc. There are many many other posible cycles like 12->6->2->5-12,  2->12->4->6->2. A route with a cycle visits one stop several times, it cannot be shorter than the same route with the cyclic part removed. Not rejecting them, but expanding them costs CPU and time.

Comment: You don't need to record path information. It is enough to mark visited cities in the graph.

Comment: @VPfB It is still failing `47 / 52 test cases passed.`
Status: `Time Limit Exceeded`

Comment: @VPfB i see we are not using `n`

Comment: @meallhour Well, it looks like that the result is still not good enough. I did not analyze the problem as thoroughly as you. I know about the Dijsktra's algo for the general case without the route length (number of flight stops) limit `k`. My intuition says that we need to record the "best" routes to each stop we have so far and do that in terms of both the total weight and the route length. Then we should ignore new candidates that are worse in both values. Of course, my intuition is sometimes right and sometimes wrong.

Comment: @meallhour We are not using `n`, but we are using `k`.

Answer (score 1):

While queueing neighbours, you're not checking if the neighbour is already visited. For example, after visiting `b` from `a`, you'll check the possibility where `a` is being visited again (basically `a -> b -> a`). Visiting the same node again in a path will never be optimal, so we can safely discard such possibilities.

Doing that is easy, you just need to maintain a set of nodes visited in the current path (using a set would allow faster lookups).

```py
heap = [(0, src, [src], k+1)]
hq.heapify(heap)
   
while heap:
    minCost, dest, path, redges = hq.heappop(heap)  
    if redges>=0:
        if dest == dst: return minCost

    for neighbor, weight in graph[dest].items():
        if redges>=0 and neighbor not in path:
            path.add(neighbor)
            hq.heappush(heap, (minCost+weight, neighbor, path, redges-1))
```